# What is an algebraic map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

From Milne's [Algebraic Varieties over Complex Numbers](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG15.pdf) note:

> COROLLARY 15.6. Any holomorphic map from one projective algebraic
>   variety to a second projective algebraic variety is **algebraic**.
>
> PROOF. Let $\varphi:V\rightarrow W$ be the map. Then the graph
>   $\Gamma_{\varphi}$ of $V$ is a closed subset of $V\times W$, and hence
>   is algebraic according to the theorem [Chow's Theorem]. Since
>   $\varphi$ is the composite of the isomorphism $V\rightarrow \Gamma_{\varphi}$ with the projection $\Gamma_{\varphi}\rightarrow W$
>   and both are **algebraic**, $\varphi$ itself is **algebraic**.

I found the following definition from *[planetmath](http://planetmath.org/node/34641/source)*

> A map $f:X\to Y$ between quasi-affine varieties $X\subset k^n,Y\subset k^m$ over a field $k$ is called **algebraic** if there is a map $f':k^n\to k^m$ whose component functions are polynomials, such that $f'$ restricts to $f$ on $X.$
>
> Alternatively, $f$ is algebraic if the pullback map $f^*:C(Y)\to C(X)$ maps the coordinate ring of $Y$, $k[Y],$ to the coordinate ring of $X$, $k[X]$.

But it didn't make much sense in the above context. 
What is the definition of an algebraic map in the context of this corollary?

Comment: It refers to the Theorem $15.5$ before, so see Shafarevich 1994, VIII 3.1 for the meaning of "algebraic" (morphism of algebraic varieties?)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't have access to the 1994 edition. But yes! from the latest one (Book 2, Springer; p.177) he means that $\varphi$ a morphism of algebraic varieties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Milne points to Shafarevich 1994, Theorem 15.5. On p. 177, [Shafarevich](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-38010-5) proves a more general result

> **Theorem 8.5.** If $X$ and $Y$ are complete algebraic varieties then any holomorphic map $f : X_{an}\rightarrow Y_{an}$ is of the form $f = g_{an}$ where $g : X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism.

So, *algebraic* in the stated corollary refers to a morphism of algebraic varieties as Dietrich Burde pointed out in the comments.